# How can I use "srand" in c++, without getting stackoverflow exception thrown?

Tags: c++, random-seed

Error message: Unhandled exception at 0x00F94619 in Cpluspluslearning.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00CD2FC0).

I am trying to make a deck of playing cards, to learn c++. Everything works fine, and I am trying to make a method for shuffling the deck. I realizes that "rand" needs to be seeded, to be "truly" random. But when I use the "srand" method i recieve the error message stated above. With no srand it works fine, but is not actually random. As this is my first C++ project, I would love some help.

Sincerely,
sad person.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

//-------------------Classes-----------------------

class Card {
public:
    string suit, color, name;
    int value;

    Card(string x, string y, string q, int z) {
        suit = x;
        color = y;
        value = z;
        name = q;
    }
    Card() {}

    string getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    string getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    string getName() {
        return name;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value
;
    }

    string toString() {
        return name + " of " + suit;
    }

};

//-----------------Variables----------------

Card deck[52];
string suits[] = {"Hearts","Spades","Diamonds","Clubs"};
string color[] = {"Red","Black"};
string name[] = { "Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King" };

//------------------Methods----------------

void createDeck() {

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 51; i++) {
        
        if (count == 13) { count = 0;}
        
        if (i <= 12) {
            deck[i] = Card(suits[0], color[0], name[count], count + 1);
        }
        else if (i <= 25) {
            deck[i] = Card(suits[1], color[1], name[count], count + 1);
        }
        else if (i <= 38) {
            deck[i] = Card(suits[2], color[0], name[count], count + 1);
        }
        else {
            deck[i] = Card(suits[3], color[1], name[count], count + 1);
        }
        count++;
    }
    
}

int randomNumber(int array[],int size) {
    int random;

    srand(time(NULL));
    random = rand() % 52;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] == random) {
            randomNumber(array, size);
        }
    }
    return random;
}

void shuffleDeck() {
    int indexes[52];
    Card shuffledDeck[52];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 51; i++) {
        indexes[i] = randomNumber(indexes, 51);
        
        shuffledDeck[i] = deck[indexes[i]];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++)
    {
        deck[i] = shuffledDeck[i];
        cout << deck[i].toString() + " ";
    }
    
}

void game() {
    createDeck();
    shuffleDeck();
}

//-----------------Main------------

int main() {
    game();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does your `randomNumber` function call itself recursively?  Without a proper exit condition on top of that

Comment: Also `srand()` should be called once per program run

Comment: Consider [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) and a modern pseudo-random number generator.

Answer (score 1):

```
indexes[i] = randomNumber(indexes, 51);
```

should be

```
indexes[i] = randomNumber(indexes, i);
```

because the rest of the array is uninitialized so far.

Also the "try again case"

```
randomNumber(array, size);
```

needs to be

```
return randomNumber(array, size);
```

otherwise you'll end up returning the original duplicate number anyway.

As a bonus, this fix will make the function tail-recursive, which means with a good compiler and tail-call optimization enabled, there will be no stack growth.

In addition, you really want to move the `srand(time(NULL))` call out of the loop [as was already commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73199822/how-can-i-use-srand-in-c-without-getting-stackoverflow-exception-thrown/73199929#comment129278913_73199822) otherwise you generate the exact same random number a whole bunch of times before the computer clock ticks and gives you a different `time(NULL)` value.